# How to define a vector in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I was just wondering, if I am setting up a vector to be a prototype of a function how do I define this?
I know that I have the option of using dynamic memory allocation, but I was wondering if instead I could just use:

`void Function(double vector[]) { }`

and in the main bit of code, allocate it some entries?

Is this an acceptable method?

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
template<class T>
void Function(std::vector<T>& vector)
{
    // do your thing
}
```

For arrays you can also do

```
template<int N>
void Function(std::array& array)
{
    // do your thing
}
```

Comment: std::vector is not a valid type, std::vector<double> would be valid.

Comment: Do. Or do not. There is no try.

Comment: @user4581301: In C++ there definitely is `try`.

Comment: @BenVoigt Ach! I am out-Yoda-ed!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should not use `vector` as it is part of the standard library (`std::vector`).

If the vector you describe has always the same dimension, you can create a structure:

```
struct Vector3D
{
  double x = 0.0;
  double y = 0.0;
  double z = 0.0;
};
```

And then use it in your function and main:

```
void Function(Vector3D v) { }

int main()
{
  Vector3D v = {1.0, 0.0, 0.0}; // Unit X
  Function(v);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using the name `vector`. The component in the standard library is `std::vector`; it's inside the namespace `std`. That's what namespaces are for. Yes, if you blow away the namespace with `using namespace std;` you'll get conflicts. So don't do that.